# To upgrade to OS X Mountain Lion, is it better to do a fresh install?

Tags: upgrade, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advantage of doing a clean Install of Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57367/advantage-of-doing-a-clean-install-of-mountain-lion)

Many of us will upgrade our existing machines to Mountain Lion, which should be out tomorrow. In my case, to be specific, I have new Macs so I don't have files to keep. In general, is there a preferred way to upgrade for power users? E.g. doing a fresh install instead of whatever default upgrade solution Apple provides?